# unable to boot to partition: "unable to mount root fs on unknown_block(0,0)"

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

What happened: unable to boot up my intel NUC with ubuntu 18.04 installed. This happened after I deleted the swap entry in /etc/fstab and rebooted.(might be other reasons)

Details: error message is `unable to mount root fs on unknown_block(0,0)`. However I have 3 kernel versions on the system and luckily one of them is able to boot. The difference is the rootfs mount in grub, the working one uses uuid.

-Working: 
`linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-22-generic root=UUID=xxxx ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`

-NOT working: 
`linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic root=/dev/sda2 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff`

I tried `avoid_disable_uuid` but after update-grub the root still use the device mount rather than uuid. Also tried to manually force using uuid but did not work. Any other ways to update the grub menus for using uuid? But in theory mount to /dev/sda2 should also work. Please feel free to drop a suggestion. Thanks!